# tar Error is not recoverable: exiting now unix

Tags: unix, tar, permission-denied

I am executing a command to tar a folder in child user as follows:

```
su - ssrun -c "tar -cvzf /root/backup/ss_conf.tar.gz /opt/mgtservices/statusService/conf"
```

and I am getting error as follows:

```
tar (child): /root/backup/ss_conf.tar.gz: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The reason what I got is the path `/root/backup/` is in ownership of root user, and the user `ssrun` is having only read permission for the files exist at path `/root/backup`.

But how can I do this task?